# Anaconda Installation Error

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to reinstall anaconda 64 bit on Windows 10 to use Python 3.6 and the installations works right till the end but it fails executing the post install script with following error.

[image]

Comment: Did you execute the installation using admin rights?

Comment: I am installing it on my personal laptop with all admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing files, try to uninstall and download it again. Don't try to pause the files, it might cause these kind of errors.

Comment: Already did the same process several times but not able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it running after installing in a different directory. Just make sure you don't install it in the default location provided. I made a new directory in C-Drive and installed anaconda in it. My install location is C:\Anaconda3. And it worked finally